# Redefining \url disallows # in url

Tags: hyperref

I want to redefine `\url` so that it writes a message to the log file. That creates a problem with the MNWE below.

@egreg explains in a comment why this fails. I could solve my problem by replacing `\url` by `\myurl` (defined in the obvious way) throughout my long multifile document. I will wait a while in hopes that someone finds a solution that works in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

See ``Q3.4: Can RANDOM.ORG help me win the lottery?'' at 
\url{www.random.org/faq/#Q3.4}.

\let\realurl\url
\renewcommand{\url}[1]{%
\realurl{#1}
\wlog{URLX #1 }
}

\url{www.random.org/faq/}.

OK so far but the next invocation of \verb!\url! fails because it
contains a \verb!#!. 

\url{www.random.org/faq/#Q3.4}.

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   Q
l.21 \url{www.random.org/faq/#Q3.4}
```

Comment: Yes, `\url` tries hard to collect its argument as late as possible in order to fix category codes. With your redefinition, the argument is absorbed in advance and it's then impossible to reset the category codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a simple redefinition is not as easy, because `\url` wants to read its argument with changed catcodes. However, redefines `\url` a little to support some "escaped" characters like `\#`, thus in this case using `\#` instead of `#` works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

See ``Q3.4: Can RANDOM.ORG help me win the lottery?'' at
\url{www.random.org/faq/#Q3.4}.

\let\realurl\url
\renewcommand{\url}[1]{%
  \realurl{#1}%
  \wlog{URLX #1 }%
}

\url{www.random.org/faq/}.

OK so far the next invocation of \verb!\url! works because it
uses \verb!\#! instead of \verb!#!.

\url{www.random.org/faq/\#Q3.4}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. Although this doesn't work in the preamble, the fix is needed in very few places.

Comment: @EthanBolker Which fix? The redefinition of `\url` can be done in the preamble *after* package `hyperref`. But as said, `\url`'s category code changes will no longer be effective and `\#` should then be used at *all* place (alternatives are `\string` and `\detokenize`).

Comment: The redefinition is of course in the preamble. The fixes in the text are to escape the few hashmarks.